# Gauge Covariant Derivative of Gauge Field

Tags: differential-geometry, gauge-theory, representation-theory, yang-mills, covariance

Given a Gauge Theory with the covariant derivative defined as:

$${(D_\mu)^A}_B={\left(\delta \partial_\mu-igA^c_\mu (\mathcal{T}_c)\right)^A}_B={\delta^A}_B \partial_\mu-igA^c_\mu {(\mathcal{T}_c)^A}_B$$

Where $\mathcal{T}_a$ and $A, B, C...$ are respectively the Generators (matrices) and the indices of the given Representation, in particular we used ${A, B, C, ...} = {a, b, c, ...}$ as the indeces of the Adjoint Representation

So $A^{a}_{\mu}$ are the components of the Gauge Field ${{\left(A_{\mu}\right)}^{b}}_{c} = A^{a}_{\mu}{{\left(\mathcal{T}_a\right)}^{b}}_{c}$ with ${{\left(\mathcal{T}_a\right)}^{b}}_{c}$ the generators of the Adjoint Representation.

My question is if it makes sense to take the Covariant Derivative of The Gauge Field in the Adjoint Representation:

$${(D_\mu)_a}^b A_{b}^{\mu}={\left(\delta \partial_\mu-igA^c_\mu (\mathcal{T}_c)\right)_a}^b A^{b}_{\mu}=\partial_\mu A_{a}^{\mu}-igA^c_\mu  {(\mathcal{T}_c)_a}^b A_{b}^{\mu} = \partial_\mu A_{a}^{\mu}+g{f_{ca}}^{b}A^c_\mu A_{b}^{\mu}$$

The reason is because $A_{\mu}$ does NOT transform in the Adjoint Representation but rather as a Connection:

$$A_{\mu} \rightarrow U A_{\mu}U^{\dagger} + \frac{i}{g}U \partial_{\mu}U^{\dagger}$$

Or maybe we say it is in the Adjoint Representation because it is true globally, i.e. if $\partial_{\mu}U = 0$?

Otherwise the problem should be from the start when we decomposed the Gauge field as ${{\left(A_{\mu}\right)}^{b}}_{c} = A^{a}_{\mu}{{\left(\mathcal{T}_a\right)}^{b}}_{c}$ already using the generators of the Adjoint Representation ${{\left(\mathcal{T}_a\right)}^{b}}_{c}$.

In GR we have that it does not make sense to take the Covariant Derivative of the connection, i.e. the Christoffell Symbols $\nabla_{\mu} {\Gamma^{\nu}_{\rho \sigma}}$, because $ {\Gamma^{\nu}_{\rho \sigma}}$ is NOT a tensor; So I am wondering if it was the case also for gauge theory, since $A_{\mu}$ is NOT in the "local" Adjoint Representation, but rather a Connection, if it makes sense to take its gauge covariant derivative.

Comment: You cannot take the covariant derivative of a gauge field for all the reasons you have mentioned yourself.

Comment: @Prahar Ok tanks, but then why everyone says that the Gauge Fields are in the Adjoint Representation? And why we write it as $A_{\mu}=A_{\mu}^{a}T_{a}$ if it's not in that Representation?

Comment: No... you can take the covariant derivative of a gauge field if you find that to be a useful intermediate step in the construction of something else which is ultimately gauge invariant.

Comment: The adjoint representation is defined for a Lie algebra so it's implicit that you're talking about the field *at a given point*. A Lie algebra is defined over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, not $C(\mathbb{R}^4)$.

Comment: @Hela - The gauge field does live in the adjoint representation. It does not transform _covariantly_ in this representation. Consequently, you can expand it in the adjoint basis, but you can't take a covariant derivative.

Comment: To address @ConnorBehan point, you are free to _define_ a particular derivative action on the gauge field and you are free to call it `covariant derivative' if you want. The main point as always is -- what is this definition good for? If you have a special use case wherein a particular choice of covariant derivative is useful for you -- then you can go ahead and use it. In general though, it is not useful.

Comment: Good point. It's just a differential operator which "would be" a covariant derivative if it acted on matter.

Comment: @Prahar Well I don't know about "useful" or not, but given a principal bundle $(P, \pi, M, G)$, the bundle $C(P)$ of principal connections is associated to the $W^{1,1}P$ gauge-natural prolongation of $P$ and therefore a connection on P induces functorially a connection on $C(P)$, thus it is possible to take (non-linear) covariant derivatives of gauge fields with respect to themselves. I *think* it simply reproduces the curvature form but I didn't post an answer because obtaining explicit formulae for this lift is a bit difficult. Nonetheless, it is definitely possible to do this uniquely.

Comment: @BenceRacskó - It would be nice if you could explain this clearly with formulae. I am interested in understanding how you can reproduce the curvature form from a ``covariant derivative''.

Comment: @Prahar Here's a heuristic: If $\phi$ (linear matter field) transforms as $U^{-1}\phi$ under a gauge transformation, with $U=1+\varepsilon X$ infinitesimally ($X$ is a Lie algebra element), then the variation of $\phi$ is $\delta\phi=-X\phi$. You can (formally) obtain the covariant differential by substituting $X=A_\mu dx^\mu$, i.e. $D\phi=d\phi-\delta\phi$ where $\delta\phi$ has been obtained from the previous formula via the above substitution. If you do this with the gauge field itself, you will get $DA_\mu=F_{\nu\mu} dx^\nu$. What I suspect is that...

Comment: @Prahar ... if the connection is lifted from $P$ to $C(P)$ via the gauge natural lift, the same formula is reproduced. I have refrained from posting this as an answer because I don't know for sure and it is fairly difficult to obtain local coordinate formulae in the gauge-natural formalism, so I'd have to work on it for a while. If I get the time to do it properly I might post an answer, but no promises.